# solving for an unknown integer using python

Tags: python, math, integer

I am new to coding in general, so after learning the basics of python from various videos on youtube, I started taking challenges on code wars. there is a particular problem I cant seem to get past. here it is :

Some numbers have funny properties. For example:

89 --> 8¹ + 9² = 89 * 1

695 --> 6² + 9³ + 5⁴= 1390 = 695 * 2

46288 --> 4³ + 6⁴+ 2⁵ + 8⁶ + 8⁷ = 2360688 = 46288 * 51

Given a positive integer n written as abcd... (a, b, c, d... being digits) and a positive integer p

we want to find a positive integer k, if it exists, such that the sum of the digits of n taken to the successive powers of p is equal to k * n.
In other words:

Is there an integer k such as : (a ^ p + b ^ (p+1) + c ^(p+2) + d ^ (p+3) + ...) = n * k

If it is the case we will return k, if not return -1.

Note: n and p will always be given as strictly positive integers.

I tried using if statements but I still was not able to find the k integer, then I tried using a for loop I still had no progress. I will love it if someone gave an assistance on how to get pass this problem.

Comment: [\[SO\]: Welcome to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
**[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**
for more asking related details. 
Also, [\[JonSkeet.CodeBlog\]: WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) might be a good point to start. **Note**: how are you going to learn if you're asking for the solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem about math and arithmetic, so it helps to think first about math and arithmetic. You can think about programming once your math is right. Math comes first. Here you are asking whether `a ** p + b ** (p+1) + ...` is a multiple of `n`. Or in other words, if it is divisible by n. See [Wikipedia: Divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor) or some other better math resource about arithmetic and divisibility.

- a, b, c, d, ... are known. p is known. So the big number of the left of the equal sign is known. Let's call X this number. `X = a ** p + b ** (p+1) + ...`.
- `n` is known too.

You are asking whether X is a multiple of n. There is division and remainder for that. The answer is yes if and only if the remainder `x % n` is 0, and in that case, k is the quotient `k = X // n`.

Important note about python: powers in python are noted using `**`, not `^`. This is important because `^` is also an operator in python, but it doesn't mean power at all. So if you write `a ^ p` you won't get an error with a helpful error message; instead, the code will execute but the result will be garbage. Be careful to write `a ** p` and not `a ^ p`.

Comment: a,b,c,d=1,2,3,4,
f=[a,b,c,d],
s = [str(i) for i in f],
abcd = int("".join(s)),
n = int(abcd),
n,
1234,  (to convert abcd to integer)